# Outlook redirect rule ignoring exceptions

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I've created an out rule as follows:

> Apply rule after message arrives
>
> Sent to 'My address'
>
> redirect to 'Redirect Address'   and move it to 'new folder'
>
> except if from 'specific addresses'   or except with '@domain.com' in
>   the senders address.

My problem is that messages from user within my own organisation (@domain.com) are also being forward and redirected, depsite specifically being told not to.

Comment: What's your Exchange Server version?

Comment: Exchange server 2010 SP2

Comment: Maybe not an answer, but certainly a workaround...

Comment: I tried some further exceptions and found that if I added an option of 'except when a specific word is found in the message header' with the specific word being 'Recieved From mail.domain.com' (the first line of the header) the exception worked as expected.  Possibly the word in senders address filter only works for the first part and not the domain. I also make an exception for 'foo@' in the sender address and this worked ok. @thims / Ray, if you think this a suitable answer please take it and you can have the credit, thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that purely internal email does not seem to be evaluated by the full smtp address, so your rule won't work if the email has never left the server.

The appropriate workaround is to include a condition that the rule applies to mail from everyone with an "@" in the address (this catches all external mail) in addition to your other conditions.

You should also still apply your exception for "@yourdomain.com" to this rule so that it captures email sent from other servers but from an address in your domain.

Comment: sorry for the necro, but this was the first result when a user googled this issue earlier today